# How to pass values into sqlloader - Oracle

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sql-loader

I have to prepare few scripts for importing data into the Oracle database, but I will have to run it on different databases.
For each table to be imported I have a data and control file:

```
table1.dat
table1.ctl
table2.dat
table2.ctl
etc..
```

For each table I have prepared separate .bat file that runs sqlloader :

table1.bat:

```
sqlldr login/password@database control=table1.ctl log=table1.log
```

It is easy and simple solution as slong as I don't have to run it on different databases and change login credentials.

What I wolud like to do is have one file with login and password that runs loading scripts for each table.

Have you got any suggestions how it could be done?

Regards

Pawel

Comment: So you want one master `.bat` file that sets a variable with the login credentials and then calls each of the other `.bat` files in turn, passing that variable which they can use in their individual `sqlldr` commands? Or one .bat file that does all the `sqlldr` calls instead of one per table?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question.

In your .bat file you can connect to any database but you sqlldr login decides on which database the import is started.

I would call a start.sql in the .bat file where I do something like this:

```
-- database 1
host sqlldr login/password@database1 control=table1.ctl log=table1_db1.log 
host sqlldr login/password@database1 control=table2.ctl log=table2_db1.log 

-- database 2
host sqlldr login/password@database2 control=table1.ctl log=table1_db2.log 
host sqlldr login/password@database2 control=table2.ctl log=table2_db2.log
```

An other option is to call import_db1.sql in your start file en write your code concerning database 1, etc.

start.sql

```
@@import_db1.sql
@@import_db2.sql
```

import_db1.sql

```
-- database 1
host sqlldr login/password@database1 control=table1.ctl log=table1_db1.log data=csvfile.csv
host sqlldr login/password@database1 control=table2.ctl log=table2_db1.log data=csvfile.csv
```

etc.

Comment: This seems to be attempting to run `sqlldr` as a command within SQL\*Plus. It's a separate executable that you run from the O/S command line. You could call out with `host` but you'd still need to supply the right credentials in those commands, so I'm not sure how this helps anyway?

Comment: You are right @AlexPoole, host had to be in the answer. I edited it. Copy + Paste is not always enough ;-)

Comment: I don't see what running SQL\*Plus and then `host` adds to the situation though - you just have to supply the credentials in each `host` call instead. But also, I don't think the OP is trying to run the scripts against multiple databases at once, the question seems to be about how you supply the credentials for a single database at run-time, in a reusable script?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't very clear, however it sounds like you just want to source username/password per server. In which case for bash you can do:

```
. /dir/to/file/.sql_password_file
```

where sql_password_file has the entry:

```
SQLLDRLOGON='user/pass'
```

then in your script you can do

```
sqlldr userid=$SQLLDRLOGON control=table1.ctl log=table1.log
```

I would look into changing your script to a loop too e.g.

```
for load in table1 table2
do
loads="control=${load}.ctl bad=${load}.bad log=${load}.log"
sqlldr $SQLLDRLOGON $loads
etc...
```